# Determine whether the system is Linear

Tags: calculus

I am not sure if I understand how to determine if a system is linear.

The equation of the system is

$y(t)=x(t) \cos(w_ct)$

I need to determine if the system is

1) Memoryless

From my understanding the $y(t)$ is memoryless because the outputs depend on the present inputs.

2)Causal

I stated that $y(t)$ is causal because any system that is memoryless is causal because it is dependent on only the present inputs.

3)Linear

Here is where I am confused. I know that the two properties to determine if a system $y(t)=T{x}$ is linear is based on

Additivity:  $y_1=Tx_1$ and $ y_2 =Tx_2$

$y=Tx=\{x_1+x_2\} = y_1+y_2$

The way I'm attempting to format is $y_1=x_1$ and $y_2=x_2$ but I don't know if I am doing it correctly.

$(x_1 +x_2) \cos (w_ct)= x_1  $ $\cos (w_ct) + x_2 \cos (w_ct)$ meaning the system is linear.

4)Time-Invariant

This is how I attempted #4

$y(t) \rightarrow y(t-t_0)$

$y(t-t_0)=x(t-t_0)\cos (w_ct)$

$x(t)\rightarrow x(t-t_0)$

$x(t-t_0)=x(t-t_0)\cos(wc_ct)= y'(t)$
Therefore $y'(t)=y(t-t_0)$

so the system is Time Invariant.

5) Stable

I believe $y(t)$ is a stable system because $cos(w_ct)$ is bounded by $-1$ to $1$.